# Same option menu in all Activities in Android

Tags: android, menu

I have 10-15 activities in my project. I want to have the option menu mostly in all Activities. Then is their any way we can do it at one place and it appears in all activities.

Also, I will like to hide the option menu in some. So, is it possible or I have to write option menu code in all activities.

Regards

Sunil

Comment: st0le's answer works perfectly. My only suggestion is that in the activities that you don't want the menu, instead of inheriting from the BaseActivity class, just inherit from Activity. In this way you won't have to override the menu related methods.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Create a Class (say **BaseActivity**) that extends Activity, and override `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected` functions.

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    // Activity code here

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item:
                // do what you want here
                return true;
            default:
               return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in the other 15-16 activities, instead of extending an Activity, you should extend **BaseActivity**.

```
public class FooActivity extends BaseActivity { 

    // Activity code here

}
```

This way, all your activities derive the options menu. For activities where you want the options menu disabled, you can override it again in that particular activity.

```
public class BarActivity extends BaseActivity { 

    // Activity code here

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       // Do Nothing
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       // Do Nothing
   }
}
```

Hopefully, it doesn't give you problems in the manifest file.

Comment: Even i thought about that but I already have a customactivity for setting the title bar in all activities. Will try implementing it in that itself.

Comment: yes, please do, it ought to work. Also report your results. :)

Comment: Will work unless you use something like ListActivity or other stuff that derives from Activity. You will have to make own ListActivities deriving from BaseActivity in this case.

Comment: works for me! though the limitation of extending only 1 class does exist.

Comment: Is BaseMenu a class or an activity?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia It's a class which extends an Activity i.e., It is also an activity only..

Comment: This solution dd not work for me. I posted the details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685648/menu-disappeared-after-extending-the-activity-with-baseactivity

Comment: Great and easy solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The solution to this problem is in your new activity add this menu method.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_home_page, menu);
    menu.removeItem(R.id.logout);
    return true;
}
```

In each activity this method will automatically appear.

If it doesn't then add it with the `inflate` call. It requires two parameters, an xml resource(the same one that you used in your original activity), and the menu object that is pass into the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method.

`menu.removeItem` will remove the menu item of whatever resource id you pass to it. 
I hope this helps those who are facing this problem.

Thank you, and happy to share this post.

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough to just extend the `BaseActivity`, you must also call `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)` and `super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)` like this in your other activities:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_second, menu);  <- remove this
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_second, menu);  //<-You should remove this

Comment: This makes the optionMenu disappear...?