# Can I add a button for settings to every options menu in my application?

Tags: android, settings, preferences, android-optionsmenu

I want to add a button for settings to the options menu of my app. Do I have to do this for each Activity or can I set it globally once?

Comment: extend an activity that has the functionality for settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can extend from Activity , put there your logic of the menu , and make all of your activities extend from the new class .

Answer (score 1):

You can @Override

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
menu= Aclass.options(menu);
return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));

}
```

in each activity, where Aclass.options(menu) a static returning method to add common options to the menu. Or, you can

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270206/same-option-menu-in-all-activities-in-android) is a good solution if you have dozens of Activities