# Menu disappeared after extending the Activity with BaseActivity

Tags: android

**I have following code in all Activity files. I will use same menu for all activities. Here is the code.**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();    
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }    
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**Instead of duplicating this code in all activities, I created a BaseActivity with following code.**

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }    
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();    
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }    
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Now all the Activities are extending BaseActivity like below.**

```
public class AddItemActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_item);
    }    
}
```

## **Problem**

Menu is disappeared due to above code. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change below line:**

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity
```

**to below**

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

I created a simple project likely what you need. Please checkout it here: https://github.com/briannl/OptionMenuExample

Comment: Seem nothing wrong, but in my code, I used AppCompatActivity instead of Activity, I think it's no more important but I little different.You just give me your a piece code snippets, so I don't what wrong in project, I might nothing wrong here(these code you provide) but happened from somewhere.