# Android Studio, options menu only opens in Main Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, android-menu

I'm having an issue trying to open a drop down menu in any activity other than my main activity right now. The three dots in the top right corner that I can click to open the menu in MainActivity still show up in PieChartActivity, but clicking them does nothing.

**EDIT : It might be important to note that I'm using the drop down menu in the first activity to navigate to the second activity. Then in that second activity, clicking the three dots in the corner doesn't open that activity's menu.

Here's my code:

In MainActivity :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.log_header_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch(id){
        case R.id.log_save_log:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SAVE LOG", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.log_add_new_metric:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ADD METRIC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.log_about_app:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ABOUT APP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.log_user_settings:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "USER SETTINGS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.log_log_mode:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LOG MODE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.log_log_settings:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LOG SETTINGS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.log_pie_mode:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PieChartActivity.class));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PIE CHART", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.log_pie_settings:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PIE CHART SETTINGS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.log_radar_mode:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RadarChartActivity.class));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "RADAR CHART", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.log_radar_settings:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "RADAR CHART SETTINGS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.log_bar_mode:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BarChartActivity.class));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BAR CHART", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.log_bar_settings:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BAR CHART SETTINGS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In log_header_menu :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:title="About This App"
    android:id="@+id/log_about_app"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

<item
    android:title="User Settings"
    android:id="@+id/log_user_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

<item
    android:title="Log"
    android:id="@+id/log_log_menu"
    app:showAsAction="never">

    <menu>
        <item
            android:title="View Log"
            android:id="@+id/log_log_mode"/>
        <item
            android:title="Log Settings"
            android:id="@+id/log_log_settings"/>
    </menu>

</item>

<item
    android:title="Pie Chart"
    android:id="@+id/log_pie_menu"
    app:showAsAction="never">

    <menu>
        <item
            android:title="View Pie Chart"
            android:id="@+id/log_pie_mode"/>
        <item
            android:title="Pie Chart Settings"
            android:id="@+id/log_pie_settings"/>
    </menu>

</item>

<item
    android:title="Radar Chart"
    android:id="@+id/log_radar_menu"
    app:showAsAction="never">

    <menu>
        <item
            android:title="View Radar Chart"
            android:id="@+id/log_radar_mode"/>
        <item
            android:title="Radar Chart Settings"
            android:id="@+id/log_radar_settings"/>
    </menu>

</item>

<item
    android:title="Bar Chart"
    android:id="@+id/log_bar_menu"
    app:showAsAction="never">

    <menu>
        <item
            android:title="View Bar Chart"
            android:id="@+id/log_bar_mode"/>
        <item
            android:title="Bar Chart Settings"
            android:id="@+id/log_bar_settings"/>
    </menu>

</item>

<item
    android:title="Save Log"
    android:id="@+id/log_save_log"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_over_write"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

<item
    android:title="Add Metric"
    android:id="@+id/log_add_new_metric"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_new"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

In PieChartActivity :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.pie_header_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch(id){
        case R.id.pie_about_app:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ABOUT APP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.pie_user_settings:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "USER SETTINGS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.pie_log_mode:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LOG MODE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.pie_log_settings:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LOG SETTINGS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.pie_pie_mode:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PieChartActivity.class));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PIE CHART", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.pie_pie_settings:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PIE CHART SETTINGS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.pie_radar_mode:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RadarChartActivity.class));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "RADAR CHART", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.pie_radar_settings:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "RADAR CHART SETTINGS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.pie_bar_mode:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BarChartActivity.class));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BAR CHART", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.pie_bar_settings:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BAR CHART SETTINGS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In pie_header_menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:title="About This App"
    android:id="@+id/pie_about_app"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

<item
    android:title="User Settings"
    android:id="@+id/pie_user_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

<item
    android:title="Log"
    android:id="@+id/pie_log_menu"
    app:showAsAction="never">

    <menu>
        <item
            android:title="View Log"
            android:id="@+id/pie_log_mode"/>
        <item
            android:title="Log Settings"
            android:id="@+id/pie_log_settings"/>
    </menu>

</item>

<item
    android:title="Pie Chart"
    android:id="@+id/pie_pie_menu"
    app:showAsAction="never">

    <menu>
        <item
            android:title="View Pie Chart"
            android:id="@+id/pie_pie_mode"/>
        <item
            android:title="Pie Chart Settings"
            android:id="@+id/pie_pie_settings"/>
    </menu>

</item>

<item
    android:title="Radar Chart"
    android:id="@+id/pie_radar_menu"
    app:showAsAction="never">

    <menu>
        <item
            android:title="View Radar Chart"
            android:id="@+id/pie_radar_mode"/>
        <item
            android:title="Radar Chart Settings"
            android:id="@+id/pie_radar_settings"/>
    </menu>

</item>

<item
    android:title="Bar Chart"
    android:id="@+id/pie_bar_menu"
    app:showAsAction="never">

    <menu>
        <item
            android:title="View Bar Chart"
            android:id="@+id/pie_bar_mode"/>
        <item
            android:title="Bar Chart Settings"
            android:id="@+id/pie_bar_settings"/>
    </menu>

</item>

</menu>
```

Comment: This will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270206/same-option-menu-in-all-activities-in-android let me know now it goes.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work for me. When I tried it, the additional options of my base menu appeared in the second menu, but they were also unresponsive. I have a menu in each activity already and as far as I can tell it's coded in the same style for each. But after opening a second activity from the menu of the first activity, I'm unable to open the menu in the second activity by clicking the dots up in the corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! For anyone having this same problem, here's the issue I had:

It was a problem with the layout of the secondary activities. Each had a header which contained the menu buttons, but that header was underneath a transparent part of another element in the layout, making the menu buttons inaccessible. I changed the layouts from constraint layout to linear layout with a vertical orientation, so that the layout element containing the main component of each secondary activity would be fixed to the bottom of the header instead of overlapping it.

Thank you to everyone who replied!

Answer (score 0):

just inflate the same menu in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` for both activities

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(***same menu id here***, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I'm afraid this didn't work for me. In a link provided in a previous comment, it was suggested that I have the secondary activities extend the base activity so that they share a menu. That suggestion and yours both have the same effect. It puts the same menu in both activities, but I can still only get the menu to drop down in the main activity.

Comment: the problem why the click doesn't happened is that bcoz the `item.getItemId()` returnes a different int than R.id.XYZ, i logged it out and found that no case in the switch have been executed bcoz of that, alternatively you can use the  xml attribute `android:onClick="itemClick"` for each item, and define a public method `itemClick(MenuItem item)` in the activity that uses the menu, this xml attribute actually works

Comment: Is there a reason the same switch statement would get the right ids and work perfectly in the main activity, but not in any activity I navigate to? Also, I'm not trying to select any of the items from within the switch statement. I'm only trying to click the three dots in the top right of the second activity and expand the menu of all the items with the code  " app:showAsAction="never" "  under them in the menu xml.

Answer (score 0):

in your `MainActivity` you are inflating `log_header_menu` menu and using switch on items ids that are not defined in the menu xml file(`R.id.log_save_log`,`R.id.log_add_new_metric`,`R.id.log_about_app`,...), thats why `item.getItemId()` returns different int than R.id.xyz, therefore nothing happens when you click any item, refactor your switch to use the ids defined in the `log_header_menu` menu xml file (`bar_about_app`,`bar_user_settings`,`bar_log_menu`,...)

Comment: Ooops. Thank you for catching that, but unfortunately that was just a mistake I made posting the question. I also have a BarChartActivity, like the PieChartActivity, and those ids were from the bar chart menu xml. Thank you again for catching that, I'll make the change in my post, but unfortunately that's not the issue in my code.